# Math.Ceiling giving "Call is ambiguous" error when using String.Length

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

Good day all.

I am getting back into C# after a few years, and am  little stuck on an error I'm receiving. I wrote a practice program to determine whether a word is a palindrome (same backwards and forwards). I am however getting an error that confuses me.

I try to call  Math.Ceiling(word.Length / 2) to get the middle of a word, but it gives me the following error:
"The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:'Math.Ceiling(decimal) and Math.Ceiling(double)"

Although I get that this is the compiler worrying about identifying the correct overloaded method, but am unsure how to indicate which I am using. I also don't get why should this matter?

Here is my full program:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string word = "Deleveled";
            word = word.ToUpper();
            bool isPalindrome = true;
            for (var i = 0; i <= Math.Ceiling(word.Length / 2); i++)
            {
                char tmp = word[word.Length - i - 1];
                if (Char.ToUpper(word[i]) != Char.ToUpper(tmp))
                {
                    isPalindrome = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(isPalindrome);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I would greatly appreciate it f anyone could help me understand what the issue is here?

My thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks @DmitryBychenko I thought that it would be something like this. So when I add a .0, does it convert to a double I assume?

Comment: either `.0` or `2d` for `double`; `2m` for `decimal`

Comment: No need to use Math Ceiling if all you need to do is get the first and second part of the string. There's actually no need for the iteration either - just use substring to split, reverse either part and attempt to match them.

Comment: @tmutton substring and reverse is a **lot** more work than comparing some values in a loop. Don't forget: even if the substring does a block-copy (which it might not - it might loop), reverse is still essentially a loop; and then compare is a loop. So that's quite possibly 3 loops plus 2 extra allocations.

Comment: You don't need to use `Math.Ceiling` in this case. For an odd-length word, the middle character doesn't matter. So you can just do `for (var i = 0; i < word.Length / 2; i++)`

Comment: @RufusL [agreed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49731198/math-ceiling-giving-call-is-ambiguous-error-when-using-string-length/49731269#comment86476441_49731269)

Comment: @MarcGravell That is true. Using these functions obviously makes it a lot easier but doesn't help someone trying to learn the basics.

Comment: The comments saying that you don't need to use Math.Ceiling don't answer the original question. Those are workarounds, but certainly not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Integer division always results in an integer; so: `word.Length / 2` returns `int` (it rounds down).

When you call `Math.Ceiling` on this, you are passing an integer, but there **is not** `Math.Ceiling(int)`. It has two choices: `Math.Ceiling(double)` and `Math.Ceiling(decimal)`, but: it could use either, and neither of those is better from the compiler's perspective.

Frankly, it might be simpler to use the general purpose "page count" formula:

```
int pages = (items + pageSize - 1) / pageSize;
```

which in this case becomes simply:

```
int upperLimit = (word.Length + 1) / 2;
```

(note that the general purpose page count formula can also be written `int pages = ((items - 1) / pageSize) + 1;`, although in this case it would be harder to substitute your fixed page size)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Marc. Does adding an extra variable not use unnecessary memory however? I have come across another suggestion to use  Math.Ceiling(word.Length / 2.0). Which would be best practice?

Comment: @phunder this variable is on the stack; an extra variable on the stack is *essentially* free - the stack has already been allocated, and exists to be used. And performing the calculation once is a **lot** more efficient than performing it once per iteration. The `Math.Ceiling(word.Length / 2.0)` involves double-precision arithmetic - which ... sure, it'll work, but it isn't really necessary. To me that says "someone needed to calculate the page count but didn't know the formula to do it with integer math" (I'm using "page count" interchangeably with whatever your half signifies - same concept)

Comment: @phunder here's an additional thought for you: if you just rounded down (`word.Length / 2`): could it ever be wrong? do you actually need to compare the middle character (of an odd-lengthed string) to itself?

Comment: @phunder "what exactly happens to a floating point number when read into a string?" - can you be **very explicit** what you mean there? because that isn't a thing that just happens by itself. If you mean `string s = someFloatingPoint.ToString();` - then: it isn't rounded *at all* - it will be rendered including a best-effort attempt to include the decimal portion

Comment: apologies, meant to say Integer, not String. I also saw that you already answered my question in your original post, which is why I deleted my last comment :)

Answer (score 0):

It is because Math.Ceiling() only accepts a double datatype parameter and most of the time we unknowingly pass int or float, so just type casting those values to double will solve the issue

typecasting the "int" value to "double" value would look like this :::

Math.Ceiling((double) (15)); //here 15 is an int value which will be typecasted to double

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).